# Panda dataframe -> Float64 or npy?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I'm currently running through the Tensorflow housing price regression [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression#the_boston_housing_prices_dataset), with the same method as in the tutorial, but with real life data.

I have all the data sliced up thanks to iloc and pandas dataframe. This leaves me in a position where I have 4 different dataframes.

1. Train data - (852,2)
2. Train labels - (852,1)
3. Test data - (364,2)
4. Test labels - (364,1)

Now these are all listed as DataFrames. See figure 1 below.

[image: Figure 1]

This does not work!

So I tried running the official tutorial through and I realised that the output of the tutorials' train and test data/labels, are floats. As seen here in figure 2.

[image: Figure 2]

So I realized its probably related to the top of the columns being str's, and the rest ints/floats. But even upon calling the dtype out, I get an error and can't actually determine its origin.

How would suggest I proceed? I'm not sure if I should abandon the Dataframe format here and stuff it in np arrays?

Comment: Your doing something wrong in creating the dataframe. Say for example train_data is 404 rows and 13 columns - but your dataframe has 852 rows and 2 columns. can you paste your code on how you created the train_data dataframe?

Comment: I didn't communicate my problem very well it would seem. The 404,13 is the tutorial example. Meaning its different data. 
My own data, that I am using, is correctly 852 samples. But unlike the tutorial that has 13 features, my own data - for now - only has 2 features.

I can paste the code, but its quite long and confusing. Its more simple to say its a .xlsl file where I've used .iloc[] to slice out the correct columns and rows. :)

Comment: right i see, sorry you did mention you were using different data. Ok in that case what isnt working specifically ? Since you're following the tutorial i'm guessing you hit an error in one of the steps?

Comment: When doing the tutorial. You automatically download the data off their website. Its already sliced and made perfect. 

I'm dealing with real world data, which means I had a very pesky made .xlsl file, that I had to slice and cut up for it to make sense. Now I then extracted the relevant data out into smaller dataframes, but they cannot be read by Tensorflow it seems. So my problem is, how do I go about getting Tensorflow to read my dataframes =)

Comment: So when I run the model. Calling upon training_data, training_labels, I get the error.


  File "/home/kongstad/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 191, in standardize_input_data
    ' but got array with shape ' + str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_87_input to have shape (852,) but got array with shape (2,)

Which is weird, cause when i call the shape on it, i get 852. Even tried with [0] and [1]

Comment: The outputs are likely not floats, but numpy arrays (given the 'float64' indicator). If you use the `.values` attribute on your dataframe, you may get the same.

Comment: More likely, your problem is with the fact that the dimensions of your labels are two dimensional, while they should be one dimensional (as in the tutorial). Since the second dimension is just 1, you can get rid of that extra dimension by either proper indexing, or using something like `np.squeeze`. Doing that, your DataFrames for the labels will likely turn into a Series as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the lack of code and example input, I can't verify that hypothesis. You're on your own to try that.

Comment: I think you are right. I managed to convert the labels into a float 32 by using the .values command. Then subsequently into a tensor by doing as such: data_trainlabels = np.asarray(train_labels, np.float32)
data_tl = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_trainlabels, np.float32)

However, the train_data will not oblige to the same thing. You say I need to get rid of the second dimension. I'll see what I can do and get back to you. Thank you